# Pygame draw.rect 2d object array black screen

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I have a problem with a program. I'm trying to code a battleship game and the problem is over here:

```
class Battleship(object):

    def __init__(self):
      
        pygame.init()
        pygame.display.set_caption('battleship')
        self.gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((DISPLAYWIDTH, DISPLAYHEIGHT))
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Tile(object):
    def __init__(self):

        self.occupied = False
        self.shipID = 0
        self.playerID = 0

    def setOccupied(self, occupied):
        self.occupied = occupied

    def setShipID(self, shipID):
        self.shipID = shipID

    def setPlayerID(self, pID):
        self.playerID = pID

class Board:

    shipSizes = [1, 2, 3]
    sizeX = 25
    sizeY = 25

    def __init__(self, playerID):
  
        self.playerID = playerID

        self.playerShips = []

        for i in range(0, len(self.shipSizes)):
            
            self.playerShips.append(Ship(i, self.shipSizes[i]))

        self.tiles = [[Tile() for i in range(self.sizeX)] for j in range(self.sizeY)]

    def drawBoard(self):
        x = 0
        y = 0
        for row in self.visual:
            for col in row:
                pygame.draw.rect(Battleship().gameDisplay, black, (x, y, CASILLA, CASILLA), LINEWIDTH)
                x = x + CASILLA
            y = y + CASILLA
            x=0
```

I don't get any errors, but the function does not work properly and only shows a black screen, checked everything else and the problem definitely lies in that part.

## Edit, i added the clas Battleship

Comment: That's not enough code to find the error. Please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: did you run it in terminal/console to see errors?

Comment: use `print()` to check values in variables which you use to draw - like `self.visual`. BTW: why do you create `Battleship()` everytime you draw `rect()` ?

Comment: Thank you for your time, should i post the whole code? other thing is, im 100 % sure the problem in my code lies in the draw board function since i tested the whole program and everything else is ok

Comment: furas, yeah i ran it and there are no errors, it's just freezes

Comment: furas, i call Battleship().gameDisplay since it is another class. is that wrong? how should i call gameDisplay?

Comment: you didn't say before that it freeze. Put `print()` in many lines to find out where/when it freeze. Maybe you run some function/class which you shouldn't

Comment: checking with print() i was only able to determine the problem was in the drawBoard function, But the Tile() class itself and the tiles array are ok, since i can print it on console, the problem is when i try to draw.rect on to that grid, i was wondering if it may be because tiles is composed of tile() objects that it gets buggy

Comment: oh, and the program itself doesn't freeze, im very sorry for being unclear, like the console continues printing out data, but eventually my whole computer just stops working and i have to restart it.

Comment: You're creating a new `Battleship` instance and with it a new `gameDisplay` inside the two for loops. That's pretty crazy. ;)  You should create a single `Battleship` instance somewhere and then just refer to its `gameDisplay` during the rest of the game, e.g. `battleship.gameDisplay`. The program looks like it could be restructured, but I can't give you specific suggestions, because the sample is still incomplete.

Comment: I think you want the `Battleship` class to be the main game class. You could give it a `Board` instance as an attribute and update and draw the board in some methods of the `Battleship` and just pass the `gameDisplay` to the board's `drawBoard` method.

Comment: BTW, to format your code correctly, you can select it in the submission window and press Ctrl+K or the `{}` symbol. That will add four extra spaces before each line of code.

Comment: Ok, thank you so very much for your help! i will try that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written this minimal example to show you what I described in the comments. The `board` instance is an attribute of the `Battleship` now and you can just call its `draw` method in the `draw` method of the battleship.

```
import pygame as pg


GRAY = pg.Color('gray20')
BLUE = pg.Color('dodgerblue1')

class Battleship(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pg.init()
        pg.display.set_caption('battleship')
        self.display = pg.display.set_mode((800, 600))
        self.clock = pg.time.Clock()
        self.fps = 30
        self.done = False
        # Is an attribute of the Battleship now.
        self.board = Board()

    def run(self):
        while not self.done:
            self.handle_events()
            self.run_logic()
            self.draw()
            self.clock.tick(self.fps)

    def handle_events(self):
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                self.done = True

    def run_logic(self):
        pass

    def draw(self):
        self.display.fill(GRAY)
        # Call the board's draw method and pass the display.
        self.board.draw(self.display)
        pg.display.flip()


class Board:

    shipSizes = [1, 2, 3]
    sizeX = 25
    sizeY = 25

    def __init__(self):
        self.tiles = [['-' for i in range(self.sizeX)] for j in range(self.sizeY)]

    def draw(self, display):
        for y, row in enumerate(self.tiles):
            for x, col in enumerate(row):
                pg.draw.rect(
                    display, BLUE,
                    (x*self.sizeX, y*self.sizeY, self.sizeX, self.sizeY), 
                    2)


battleship = Battleship()
battleship.run()
```